# Why is there no unsigned minimum?

Tags: c

1] DATA TYPE LIMITS :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
int main(){
        printf("\n INT_MAX : %d %x \n",INT_MAX,INT_MAX);
        printf("\n INT_MIN : %d %x \n",INT_MIN,INT_MIN);
        printf("\n SHRT_MAX : %d %x \n",SHRT_MAX,SHRT_MAX);
        printf("\n SHRT_MIN : %d %x \n",SHRT_MIN,SHRT_MIN);
        printf("\n LONG_MAX : %ld %lx \n",LONG_MAX,LONG_MAX);
        printf("\n LONG_MIN : %ld %lx \n",LONG_MIN,LONG_MIN);
        printf("\n USHRT_MAX : %u %x \n",USHRT_MAX,USHRT_MAX);
        printf("\n UINT_MAX : %u %x \n",UINT_MAX,UINT_MAX);
        printf("\n ULONG_MAX : %lu %lx \n",ULONG_MAX,ULONG_MAX);
        return 0;
}

o/p :
-----
 INT_MAX : 2147483647 7fffffff 
 INT_MIN : -2147483648 80000000 
 SHRT_MAX : 32767 7fff 
 SHRT_MIN : -32768 ffff8000 
 LONG_MAX : 9223372036854775807 7fffffffffffffff 
 LONG_MIN : -9223372036854775808 8000000000000000 
 USHRT_MAX : 65535 ffff 
 UINT_MAX : 4294967295 ffffffff 
 ULONG_MAX : 18446744073709551615 ffffffffffffffff
```

Why is there no unsigned minimum ?

Comment: Are there many platforms that can't represent 0?

Comment: Isn't it 0U irrespective of the platform? Or can any platform choose other than 0U as unsigned min.

Comment: Unsigned types don't represent negative values, guess whats the minimum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unsigned minimum is zero, always (that's *by definition* the smallest unsigned value). So, probably the spec authors decided it was unnecessary to add them.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is:
`U<ANY_TYPE>_MIN` is **always** 0U; 
that's how unsigned types are defined. There is, therefore, no need for 
these identifiers. So defining `ULONG_MIN` etc is redundant.